# Calculating the volume of the mountain $(x^2+y^2+z-2)^2+z-1=0$ where $z\ge0$

Tags: integration

So we can calculate the volume by $$\iiint_V1 dxdydz$$ using cylindrical coordinates that is equal to $$\iiint_{V'} r drd\theta dz$$ But I am not sure on how to extract the limits of the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates we have that

$$(r^2+z-2)^2 + z - 1 = 0$$

Rearrange this to get

$$(r^2+z-2)^2 = 1-z$$

then take square roots on both sides

$$r^2 = 2-z \pm \sqrt{1-z}$$

This gives us the integral

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_{\sqrt{2-z - \sqrt{1-z}}}^{\sqrt{2-z + \sqrt{1-z}}}r\:dr\:dz\:d\theta$$

The bounds for $z$ come from the second equation. Since the left side is a square, $1-z$ must be nonnegative. Integrating gives us

$$2\pi \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-z}\:dz = \frac{4\pi}{3}$$